# Different API Levels

Tags: java, android, api

I have created a Gin Rummy Game using minSdkVersion=8 and targeting 16. I was wondering for the target amount of devices you can run the game on devices that have a higher API level, for example API level 18.

I was wondering about this so that I can see about the target amount of devices available.

Thanks
Sammy

Comment: This isn't really what Stack Overflow is for. SO is for specifical problems and solutions about code. Info/statistics about a userbase aren't the kind of answers provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest just changes how devices behave at run time.

Devices basically use this to decide whether to run your app in a 'backward compatibility mode'.

*E.g.* Setting it to a target of API 10 (Gingerbread) will mean that devices will still use the 'visual styling' of Gingerbread for your app even if their API version is greater than 10. It is good practise to make the target version the latest version available, so the style used by your application is up to date for all versions. (i.e. `targetSdkVersion` being 22 at present)

Comment: So if I create it to API 16, will API 17+ be able to run it?

Comment: Yes, it does not affect versions that can run it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm assuming that goes for APIs 15 and lower as well?

Comment: My answer explains that it is nothing to do with determining which API version can run your app. All versions above and equal to your `minSdkVersion` will support the app